# VB.NET: LINQ Query on DataTable - WHERE Id >=0

Tags: database, vb.net, linq

**Hey people,**

I am bugfixing an application for some friends of mine. They are using VB.NET and Windows Forms, while I am in team C#/WPF/ASP. My knowledge about LINQ is also very limited even if its all .NET. I hope you can help me.

**The situation**
There are two combos on the form.
They are getting their data from the same table *status*.
The order of the status objects depends on the id-column.
The second combo shall only contain status having id >= combo1.id. So that the user can only select status in the second combo that are "greater-equal" than the status in the first combo.
The smallest status.id is 3.

**The code**
(please ignore the useless back and forward casting of *index* etc. I wanted to show you the code as I revieved it.)

```
                    Dim index As String = cmbStatusFrom.SelectedValue.ToString()
                    If index = "0" Then
                        index = "1"
                    End If

                    Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = _
                        From status In ContextDataTable.AsEnumerable() _
                        Where status.Field(Of Integer)("Id") >= Integer.Parse(index) _
                        Select status
```

**The problem**
Without

```
If index = "0" Then  
    index = "1"  
End If
```

the resulting datatable contains one more row than it should. 
(0 means that the empty-item has been selected in the first combo) The row has id = 0 (like the empty-row)

Again, the smallest existing id is 3. So it should not make any difference if one uses >=0, 1, 2 or 3. But it seemingly does. Or more likely, there is some really stupid mistake in the code and which I just can't find.

Anyone has got an idea what the problem is?

I do appreciate any help. :-)

greetz steven

Comment: So the new row you are getting, without setting index to '1', has a id of 0? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to help, but I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Given the information you have here, that code should work. The only unknown is the actual datatype of the value of the combo, but unless the `.Field(Of T)` is throwing an InvalidCastException, you should be good there. I wrote the following code and threw it into a unit test project, and everything came out good . . . at least with regard to the length of the resulting set of data.

### Code

```
<TestCase(0, ExpectedResult:=4)>
    <TestCase(1, ExpectedResult:=4)>
    <TestCase(2, ExpectedResult:=3)>
    <TestCase(3, ExpectedResult:=2)>
    <TestCase(4, ExpectedResult:=1)>
    <TestCase(5, ExpectedResult:=0)>
    Public Function tmptest(ByVal selected As Integer) As Integer

        Dim d As New DataTable
        d.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("id", GetType(Integer)))
        For j = 0 To 5
            Dim r = d.NewRow()
            r("id") = j
            d.Rows.Add(r)
        Next

        If selected = 0 Then selected = 1
        Dim query = From status In d.AsEnumerable()
                    Where status.Field(Of Integer)("id") > selected
                    Select status


        Return query.Count
    End Function
```

### Results

[image: Test Results]